# Возможно ли: "в том числе среди прочих..."?

Tags: пунктуация, лексическая-сочетаемость

> Игра в шахматы перебивается несколькими интермедиями, в том числе
>   среди  прочих, выходами знаменосцев – они делают удивительные трюки с
>   флагами.

Может так:

*...в том числе выходами знаменосцев – они делают удивительные трюки с флагами.*

Или:

*...в том числе – выходами знаменосцев: они делают удивительные трюки с флагами.*

Comment: Трюки с флагами... (Т. — эффектный искусный манёвр, или технический приём, как правило, опасный или невыполнимый для неподготовленного человека). Это не трюк, а жонгляж, жонглирование: «...знаменосцев, удивительно ловко синхронно жонглирующих флагами».

Comment: Запятая после "прочих" точно лишняя.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - вообще-то, если сохранять оригинальный формат, запятой ПЕРЕД НЕ ХВАТАЕТ для правильности. "В том числе, среди прочих,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для меня такое сочетание звучит чудовищно: эти обороты различаются случаями употребления и управлением (даже если отвлечься от случившейся тавтологии). В "числе прочих" здесь лишнее, оно больше подошло бы к случаю:

> В числе прочих интермедий, которыми в тот вечер прерывалась игра в
>   шахматы, были выходы знаменосцев.

Для употребления выражений "в числе прочих(-его)" или "в частности" не нужен предшествующий контекст с упоминанием общего понятия, в то время как для "в том числе" он обязателен ("то число" - буквальная ссылка на него). Поэтому если для автора выходы знаменосцев являются частным случаем интермедии, то достаточно употребить"в том числе" (= в числе упомянутых интермедий):

> Игра в шахматы прерывается несколькими интермедиями, в том числе
>   выходами знаменосцев – они делают удивительные трюки с флагами.